# IIS: How to redirect url to another domain based on the sub domain

Tags: iis, rewrite, url, rules

I am having one website which is hosted in IIS (my.serverfault.com) and having new website which is deployed in openshift (angular.serverfault.com)

We have to allow the users to access the new website from old website (reverse proxy using IIS)

Ex. If user hits my.serverfault.com/angular IIS should serve the content in the angular.serverfault.com but the url in the client browser should not changed to angular.serverfault.com. URL should only my.serverfault.com/angular

Yes Lesli i have tried i am using below rules now i am getting the error

"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Comment: Microsoft documented everything you might need https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing So have you tried it?

Comment: Yes Lex Li i have tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tried based on the url i have updated my latest error in the question

Comment: Hi Lex Li, i have again tried with the docs which you recommended  it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The below rules can be applied in IIS for the problem

http://[^/]+/(.*)" />